# Copy object's grandchild property to a newly created object without much code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a way to do the following in a more efficient way?
(I use coffeescript, so maybe there's a coffeescript specific solution as well?..)

```
oldObj =
  parent:
    child:
      grandchild: "I'm a grandchild!"
newObj =
  parent:
    child:
      grandchild: null
newObj.parent.child.grandchild = oldObj.parent.child.grandchild
```

I cannot simply do `newObj.parent = oldObj.parent` because `oldObj.parent` may contain `anotherChild` and `yetAnotherChild` and so on - and I don't know what else it contains (and don't wanna know), I need only `child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a general recursive function to add properties to object

```
oldObj =
    parent:
        child:
            grandchild: "I'm a grandchild!"

addPropertyToObject = (obj, property, valueProperty) ->
    if typeof property == 'string'
        property = property.split(".")

    obj[property[0]] = obj[property[0]] || {}
    tmpObj = obj[property[0]]

    if property.length > 1
        property.shift()
        addPropertyToObject tmpObj, property, valueProperty
    else
        obj[property[0]] = valueProperty
    obj

newObj = addPropertyToObject {}, "parent.child.grandchild", oldObj.parent.child.grandchild
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has `set()` and `get()` functions for this; they even support arrays in object keys.